# Alchemy: Physician perk

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

From the wiki:

> Potions you mix that **restore** Health, Magicka or Stamina are 25% more
>   powerful.

Just to be sure, it won't affect potions that *regenerate* now will it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it won't. I just tested it and there is no effect on potions that regen health, magicka, or stamina.